# DIV over table (position: absolute, z-index: 1000) - not working

Tags: html, css-position

DIV has `style: positon: absolute, z-index: 1000`.
But displayed under table.

Why?

PS: Table does not have `z-index`

[screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5794162/screenshot1.png)

Comment: please share your complete code

Comment: z-index: 99999 - no effect

Comment: comlete code very big (many css styles files - from Wordpress CMS) and plugin jquery.multiple.select

Comment: Complete. Parent TD has "hidden:overflow" )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don’t forget that z-index still respects parent’s overflow. So if you still can’t see something despite a z-index in the millions, check it’s not being cropped by an

```
overflow:hidden
```